# Extract Missing Values from Data Set

Tags: excel, function, logic

I am trying to create a spreadsheet that will enable me to determine a solution that can identify `missing products` usually due to theft, or human error to start.

There are two static pieces of data.

> 1) Each Product comes in 18 units.
>
> 2) The 18 Units follow the same size run  1*5.5; 2*6; 2*6.5; 3*7; 3*7.5; 2*8; 2*9; 1*10.

I have access to the sizes sold, as well as those remaining on-hand. For example, Product A sold 14 Units, however there are only 3 present on-hand 1*6; 1*8; 1*9, clearly 1 is missing.

I want to identify the possible missing sizes by referencing the data sold, and on-hand quantity to the size run. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Post formatted sample data with expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Do you prefer a macro or excel formulas?
(cell with your size runs = X)

```
Find position of *  = FIND("*";X)
Find position of space  =FIND(" ";X) 

First number (i)  = LEFT(X;position of * -1)
Second number (i)  = MID(X;position of * + 1 ;(position of space - position of * )-1)
```

Remove the information you already have X = RIGHT(X;position of space-1)
Repeat (for i = n)

You can not check if the difference in the second numbers are consistent with the first numbers.

```
Difference Second number = ( Second number (n+1) - Second number (n) )
relative difference = Difference Second number / First number (n)
```

If the relative difference is consistent there is no problem. Else you have a deviation.